# Maven dependency exclusion is not working as expected

Tags: java, maven

I have added a dependency in my parent pom under dependecymanagement.

> ParentPom

```
<dependecyManagement>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>some version</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In my ***child pom*** I am simply inherting the dependecy without version

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I do dependency tree on my child pom its still showing commons-logging in tree which is excluded in parent pom .

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-logging:commons-logging
```

This is the dependecy tree from child.

```
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:parent version .RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:some version:compile
```

Though version no is getting inherited why not excluded dependency is getting inherited from parent pom is what I am looking for.

> Am I assuming anything wrong? or is that how maven behaves?

Valid solutions would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: it only inherits versions, you still have to do the exclusion in the child.

Comment: @EssexBoy Are you sure? Do you have a source for this? The comment of khmarbaise in https://stackoverflow.com/q/39835372/927493 suggests otherwise.

Comment: You don't need to define the same dependency in child pom when it is already defined in parent pom. You are overriding the exclusions in your child pom. Remove the dependency from child pom.

Comment: @Guest, Ours is a multi module project. I cannot remove the dependency from child pom.

Comment: First exclude in dependencyManagement is sufficient furthermore If you like to analyze a dep tree you shouldn't filter everything important out...cause take a look where this exactly is coming from...cause I assume that this dependency is inherited from somewhere else...and not only from spring-core...check the whole dependency tree....

Comment: @Khmarbaise I did a dependency tree on parent pom also.I could see only spring-core has the dependency that needs to be excluded. I already tried excluding from parent pom dependency management but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Sorry but without the full poms it's not possible to get into this..?